# Selenium is not finding the element I need?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want Selenium to click on the judges tab, after I enter the tournament name. (If you need a tournament name to enter enter "TFA State") Every time I try to look for the Judges Element it gives back an error. If it can't find it by LINK_TEXT is there any other alternatives that allow me to click the link?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.tabroom.com/index/index.mhtml'

driver.get(url)

name = input('What Tournament(spell it exactly as you would on tabroom, case sensitive): ')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="searchtext"]').send_keys(name)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search"]/form/button').click()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, name).click()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Judges").click()
```

The error is on the last line looking for the Judges element

Comment: Where did you switch to the new tab that was opened?

Comment: Can you be more clear about the link you're trying to find? If I enter "TFA State" in the search box, the resulting page doesn't have any button, link, or other content with the text "Judges".

Comment: _I want Selenium to click on the judges tab_ If it's a **tab**, why are you searching for it as a **link**?

Comment: All good I figured it out it is because I didn't change tabs because when you go to the TFA State tournament it opens up a new page So I just switched over to that tab and that fixed the issue
    old = driver.current_window_handle
    tabs = driver.window_handles
    for tab in tabs:
        if (tab!=old):
            driver.switch_to.window(tab)